# Cant get channel with ID - discord.js

Tags: javascript

```
//Discord.js 11.6.4 (typescript)

import * as Discord from "discord.js"

const bot = new Discord.Client({
    disableEveryone: true
})

bot.login('token')

//This function get Channel. For send message requires TextChannel.
bot.channels.get('id') //Discord.Channel

//Cache is undefined
bot.channels.cache

//Fetch is undefined
bot.channels.fetch

//Find is undefined :(
bot.channels.find('id')

//Get1, Get2 is undefined
Discord.get(bot.channels.get(), 'id').send()
```

How to get channel?

```
//discord.js 11.6.4 (typescript)
let channel: Discord.TextChannel

function sendToDiscord(msg: string): void {
    if (!channel) return
    channel.send(`bot say's: ${msg}`)
}

bot.on('message', (ev) => {
    channel = ev.channel
})
```

I try this. Its not automatically. Its not for me.

help me please. Its for my project

I use all methods for get channel and send message. All returns message error. I cant install latest aplication version must be discord.js@11.6.4

I use ts to js compilator

Comment: The `Discord.js` version `11.6.4` is quite outdated, and it's highly recommended to consider upgrading to a newer version as older versions might have issues or lack support for newer Discord features.

Answer (score 0):

You should try obtaining id of the channel in the `message` event. Only in that event you can get `message.channel` by parsing async function.

```
import { Client, Message, TextChannel, ClientOptions } from "discord.js";
import { token } from "./config.json";

interface MyClientOptions extends ClientOptions {
  disableEveryone?: boolean;
}

const client = new Client({
  disableEveryone: true,
} as MyClientOptions);

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`${client.user?.tag} is online`);
});

client.on("message", async (message: Message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return; // If the message is from a bot, ignore it
  const channel = message.channel as TextChannel;
  const content = message.content;
  console.log(
    `Message sent in ${channel.name} with id ${channel.id} by ${message.author.tag}: ${content}`
  );
});

client.login(token);
```

The output in the console is:
`Message sent in admin-channel with id 1099312134321606806 by wolfie: test2`

Keep in mind that I'm using token from `config.json` file so you should **change it accordingly to your code**.

And lastly, please consider upgrading to the latest version, as it doesn't lack of any features.